# list is coming empty in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code I am trying to getting the list of operators.

list of operator contains some details .But I am getting null .How to access the operator list from getoperatorlist class .

can any one help me how to access the operator list from pojo classes.

From the below fragment I am getting the response from the Api 
response:

```
{"list":[{"email":"Narendra.Varada@chipmonk.in","id":"2","mobileNumber":"6728768768","username":"Narendra1993"},{"email":"abc@gmail.com","id":"4","mobileNumber":"6253957809","username":"abc"}]}
```

After response I am Storing in variabels and then adding to the arraylist and then sending to the adapter.

Fragement.java:

```
@Override
                    public void onResponse(Call <Operator> call, Response <Operator> response) {

                            if (response != null && response.code ( ) == 200 && response.isSuccessful ( )) {
                                Operator operator = response.body ();
                                arrayList = String.valueOf (new ArrayList <String> ( ));
                                arrayList=new Gson ( ).toJson (operator.getList ());
                               // Operator operator = response.body ();
                                //operator=lists;


                                Log.d ("lists", arrayList);

 SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter ((Context) getActivity ( ),arrayList);//error in this line

                                // Setting Mode to Single to reveal bottom View for one item in List
                                // Setting Mode to Mutliple to reveal bottom Views for multile items in List
                                ((SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setMode (Attributes.Mode.Single);

                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter (mAdapter);
```

Adapter.java:

```
 public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {


    private Context mContext;
    private  List<GetOperatorList> operatorlist;
    ArrayList arrayList;
    Dialog myDialog;
    String building_name;


    public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List <GetOperatorList> lists) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.operatorlist = lists;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_operator_item, parent, false);
        myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        GetOperatorList obj = operatorlist.get(position);

       // obj.getUsername ();
        //obj.getMobileNumber ();
        //obj.getUsername ();
        viewHolder.tvName.setText (obj.getUsername ());
```

POJO Classes:

Operator.java:

```
public class Operator {

    @SerializedName("list")
    private List <GetOperatorList> list;

    public List <GetOperatorList> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List <GetOperatorList> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

GetOperatorList.java:

```
public class GetOperatorList {

    @SerializedName ("email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName ("id")
    private String id;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    @SerializedName ("mobileNumber")
    private String mobileNumber;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @SerializedName ("username")
    private String username;

}
```

Comment: You can't access directly, you have to pass that `class object` to `Adapter` class from `Activity` or `Fragment`

Comment: post you activity or fragment code where you getting this response

Comment: And check whether you are getting value from API and properly added to list.

Comment: Are you sure your list in json object is named "list"

Comment: post you full adapter, activity or fragment code

Comment: All of you please check my updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are getting a list of operators correctly inside activity/fragment. If not, then you need to detect why you are not getting data correctly. 
If you are getting data inside fragment/activity I would suggest that you remove passing list of data inside constructor. Make a separate method inside Adapter.

```
public void setData(List<GetOperatorList> data){
    operatorList.clearAll(); //Clear all data
    operatorList.addAll(data); //Add new data
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //Refresh data
}
```

Call this method when API call for getting data finishes succesfully.

Also, you don't need to call `getAdapterPosition()` inside `onBindViewHolder` since you already have the position inside `onBindBindViewHolder`

Edit:
From fragment code, you are adding single name to the list and then you are initializing adapter with this list with one name. First parse all data of type GetOperatorList and add to one list. Then set this data to the adapter.

Comment: Do you get some response from the backend? Are you getting 200 response code? What do you get inside this log:  Log.d ("Status", Lists);

Comment: You are setting to the retrofit GsonConverterFactory. And you have Response<Operator> so response should be parsed with gson and this response should contain list of your data. You should retrieve list of data from response directly without additional parsing and JsonObjects

Comment: Yes.....{"list":[{"email":"Narendra.Varada@chipmonk.in","id":"2","mobileNumber":"6728768768","username":"Narendra1993"},{"email":"abc@gmail.com","id":"4","mobileNumber":"6253957809","username":"abc"}]}

Comment: without parsing how to parse it

Comment: So then response.body ( ) is already your data of Operator type. And call response.body().getList() to get list of operators. With Gson().toJson(response.body()) you are converting that data to string which is not necessary.

Comment: Pass the whole list of data to the adapter (not just name). And then in onBindViewholder call operatorList.get(position).getUsername() to get name

Comment: And you are doing a duplicate job. You already have response.body() of Operator data type (which is parsed by Gson already). You don't need to do anything. Call list of data from this object and pass to adapter

Comment: Inside your response all you need is: Operator operator = response.body();  adapter.setData(operator.getList());

Comment: How to pass the lists to Adapter this is my question

Comment: I wrote method in the answer. This needs to be inside adapter class. Initialize empty adapter inside fragments onCreateView() and on network response call this setData method from adapter

Comment: Also, initialize empty operatorList inside adapter so you don' get NPE when setting the data

Comment: This is because you are passing String to the adapter. Just pass operator.getList() to the adapter you don't need to do anything else

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to correct your code in the **onBindViewHolder()** method.

To get the record for an individual row from your operator list you should write :

```
GetOperatorList obj = operatorlist.get(position);
```

And then you can access every field of that particular record like this :

```
obj.getUsername();       
obj.getMobileNumber();
```

and so on.

Comment: Ohk, then please log the data of  List<GetOperatorList> operatorlist before you are setting the recyclerview adapter and also put a condition whether the operatorlist is not null and its size is greater than 0, like this, 


`if(operatorlist  !=null && operatorlist.size>0){
     // set your recyclerview adapter here with your operatorlist object
}`

Comment: Operatorlist is null and size is 0

Comment: Then please post your code fetching the list data from any API or source.

Comment: @theduck can you please check the updated code and let me know the changes

Answer (score 0):

Initialise Array list like below in your fragment

```
 private List<Operator.GetOperatorList> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

then n place of

```
 Operator operator = response.body ();
 arrayList = String.valueOf (new ArrayList <String> ( ));
 arrayList=new Gson ( ).toJson (operator.getList ());
```

replace below code

```
arrayList.clear();
arrayList.addAll(response.body().getList());
```

Comment: When I am try to print the arrayList.addAll(operator.getList()) is returning true

Comment: Why are you printing anything? You need to pass Array of GetOperatorList objects inside adapter. And you have everything already. response.body().getList() is your desired list that needs to be inside adapter.